# There is no 'package.json' - node-webkit app

Tags: node-webkit, package.json

I'm making my first desktop application using node-webkit.
I followed all the steps to package the app on windows but I'm getting this error:

```
There is no 'package.json' in the package, please make sure the 'package.json' is in the root of the package.
```

Although the package is in the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my mistake. In fact, I was compressing the folder containing the package json and the other files. So what I made was like that:

```
App.zip
|
|-App
   |-package.json
   |-Other files
```

What is correct is this:

```
App.zip
   |-package.json
   |-Other files
```

Answer (score 0):

sample package.json file

```
{
        "name": "name of app",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "main": "index.html",
        "single-instance": true,
        "node-remote": "<local>",
        "window": {
            "title": "name to show in title bar",
            "icon": "icon to show in titlebar",
            "position": "center",
            "min_width": 1024,
            "min_height": 600,
            "toolbar": true,
            "width": 1362,
            "height": 768
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "express": "3.x"
        },
        "webkit": {
            "plugin": true
        }
    }
```